# Home screen wallpaper gets zoomed when it goes to the background

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have scheduled background service to change device home screen wallpaper periodically. The wallpaper changes successfully and they are perfectly set to the screen size.
But when I move away from the home screen and return the image gets zoomed in too much,leaving only a portion of the image visible.Below given is the code I use

```
    Bitmap theBitmap = null;
    try {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        theBitmap = Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(PhotoPath)
                .asBitmap().into(width, height).get();

        WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(mContext);
        wm.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);

        wm.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
            wm.setBitmap(theBitmap);Album
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Try not to rush and flag this question as a duplicate. There are questions stating the image appears zoomed in when set but My wallpaper gets set perfectly,atleast initially it does. Why does it zoom in when I move homescreen to the background.

[image: Image as long as I do not perform any action taking the homescreen to the background][image: Image after I move from homescreen and get back(Zoomed in)]

Comment: have u found the answer?